# Oracle query with field with CASE...WHEN depending of a prevous field of a sub-query

Tags: oracle, subquery, case-when

I don't know exactly (in order to avoid to rewrite the condition) how to re-use a field based on a SELECT in another field (based on a CASE WHEN).

**Here my query:**

```
SELECT  U.ID AS ID, 
        U.TITLE, 
        U.VALID_FROM, 
        U.VALID_TO,          
        (
            SELECT LEVEL 
            FROM UNITS_LEVELS L
            WHERE L.ID = U.ID
        ) AS LEVEL, 
        CASE LEVEL
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END AS IS_DIRECTORATE, 
        CASE LEVEL
            WHEN 4 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END AS IS_UNIT,   
FROM UNITS U;
```

So here I would like to create a the fields *IS_DIRECTORATE* and *IS_UNIT* from the field LEVEL created previously from the SELECT sub-query.

Could you please help me to do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for that just join them and create two columns with desired values:

```
SELECT  U.ID AS ID, 
        U.TITLE, 
        U.VALID_FROM, 
        U.VALID_TO,          
        L.LEVEL, /*if you need this one keep it here */
        CASE L.LEVEL /*and here the columns as you've defined them */
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END AS IS_DIRECTORATE, 
        CASE L.LEVEL
            WHEN 4 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END AS IS_UNIT,   
 FROM UNITS U, UNITS_LEVELS L
WHERE L.ID = U.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your query to use an explicit join between the two tables, which gets around a lot of the problems you are having:

```
SELECT
    U.ID AS ID,
    U.TITLE,
    U.VALID_FROM,
    U.VALID_TO,
    L.LEVEL,
    CASE L.LEVEL WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_DIRECTORATE,
    CASE L.LEVEL WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_UNIT
FROM UNITS U
LEFT JOIN UNITS_LEVELS L
    ON L.ID = U.ID;
```

Note carefully that to preserve the original behavior of your query we use a *left* join here, and not an inner join.  The subquery you had to determine the level would not cause a record in `UNITS` to ever be filtered off.